# Keras or TensorFlow Examples for Working with Large Text Datasets (~10M Sentences)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, tensorflow, keras

I'm looking for any tutorials or examples for using either Keras or TensorFlow on large text datasets (at least a few million sentences). I've looked at some of the examples using the `fit_generator()` method in Keras, but these are mostly tailored to image classification and involves really minimal preprocessing. I've also looked into using the newer `HDF5Matrix` class in Keras, and have continued to run out of memory with batch sizes larger than 20.

Are there any other useful data reading/streaming tools in TensorFlow that could be used to solve this problem? Are there examples for how to do standard NLP preprocessing in such a pipeline in a memory-efficient way before feeding to a model? Any references would be appreciated. Thanks for reading.